# pattern is not matching when description is taken from database

Tags: php, mysql, preg-match

I have the following php program

```
<?php
$pattern = "/.*PURCHASE.*?\d{2}\w{3}\s(.*)Ref:.*/";
$description = "PURCHASE Card no.: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 13MAR IDEAMONEY MUMBAI Ref: 031352203423 ";
if(preg_match($pattern,$description,$matches))
 {
print_r($matches);
 }
?>
```

this is giving the exact output as

```
Array ( [0] => PURCHASE Card no.: 5497XXXXXXXX1502 13MAR IDEAMONEY MUMBAI Ref: 031352203423 [1] => IDEAMONEY MUMBAI )
```

but the problem is when i save the contents of $description in mysql DB and fetch the same and perform the pattern matching its failing to match.

my new code looks like this

```
<?php
$pattern = "/.*PURCHASE.*?\d{2}\w{3}\s(.*)Ref:.*/";

include 'dbconnection.php';
$conn = get_dbConnection(); 
$query1 = "select * from MY_TABLE_NAME";
$stmt = $conn->query($query1);

while($result=$stmt->fetch())
{
 $description = $result['MY_COLUMN_NAME'];
if(preg_match($pattern,$description,$matches))
{
print_r($matches);
}
?>
```

it is taking the same description content from database but its not matching.

If i replace the above $pattern by

```
$pattern = "/.*/";
```

it is giving the output as

```
Array ( [0] => PURCHASE Card no.: 5497XXXXXXXX1502 13MAR IDEAMONEY )
```

instead of giving

```
 Array ( [0] => PURCHASE Card no.: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 13MAR IDEAMONEY MUMBAI Ref: 031352203423 )
```

so the problem why the matching is not happening is it is neglecting the text after IDEAMONEY by itself.

how to resolve this?????

Comment: Is it saved in database as the complete string? That seems to be the most obvious here.

Comment: yess it is saved as same as i have mentioned in $description variable

Comment: Are you sure the "space" before `MUMBAI` is not a line feed character? If you add an "s" at the end of the regex like this: `/.*PURCHASE.*?\d{2}\w{3}\s(.*)Ref:.*/s`, does it work then?

Comment: thank you @trincot it worked when i add 's' at the end of the regex.

Comment: OK, I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string in your database has a newline just before `MUMBAI`. So either:

- Update the value in the database so it does not have newlines in it, or
- Change your regular expression so that the dot also can match newlines. This you can do by adding the [`s` pattern modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

  ```
  $pattern = "/.*PURCHASE.*?\d{2}\w{3}\s(.*)Ref:.*/s";
  ```